# Linear approximation by rational number to square root of 15

Tags: calculus, approximation

*Use linear approximation of the function $f$ given by $f(x) =\sqrt{16-x}$ at the point x = 0 to find an approximation of $\sqrt{15}$ by a rational number (i.e. fraction).*

What I have so far:

$$L = \sqrt{16-0} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{16-0}} \cdot  \sqrt{15}\Rightarrow L = 4 - \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{15}$$

I don't know whether that's correct, and suppose that it is correct, how do I turn this into a fraction? Or is the answer simply: $$\frac{32-\sqrt{15}}{8}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: What is your linear approximation  of $f(x) = \sqrt{16-x}$ at the point $x = 0$? It needs to be of the form $f(x) \approx a+bx$, passing through $(0,f(x))$ and having the same gradient as the tangent at that point.

Comment: @Henry 4 - (1/8) * (x - 0), so basically 4 - (1/8)x.

Comment: OK, so what should $x$ be so that $\sqrt{16-x}=\sqrt{15}$?  What do you get when you use that $x$ in $4-\frac18x$?  Is that close to $\sqrt{15}$?

Comment: @Henry then x should be 1, and if I fill that in then I get 31/32. Is that the correct answer??

Comment: No.That is much too small to be close to $\sqrt{15}$.  $4-\frac18\times 1 \not = \frac{31}{32}$

Comment: Oops I mean 31/8

Comment: Better.  And indeed correct. $\sqrt{15} \approx 3.873$ while $\frac{31}{8} = 3.875$.  So they are reasonably close

Comment: Okay thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments:

- You found that $\sqrt{16-x} \approx 4-\dfrac{x}{8}$ near $x=0$.
- So letting $x=1$ suggests $\sqrt{16-1} \approx 4-\dfrac{1}{8}$, i.e. $\sqrt{15} \approx \dfrac{31}{8}$.
- Indeed they are quite close as $\sqrt{15} \approx 3.873$ while $\frac{31}{8} = 3.875$.

In fact what you have done is use the tangent at one point on a parabola to approximate the value at another point nearby.

[image]